# Django: Create a dynamic sidebar template and use it in other templates

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

NOTE: This question is not about creating or using a base template!

I'm creating a `products` app in my project, using only django and html/css, and all pages in this part has a sidebar nav menu that categorizes different product models and types. So this sidebar will be used in all other product pages.

Here is my `views.py` file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import (
    Product,
    Usage,
    SubUsage,
    MainModel,
    PumpType,
    HeadFlowDataSet,
)


def products_usage_main(request):
    product_queryset = Product.objects.all()
    usage_queryset = Usage.objects.all()
    sub_usage_queryset = SubUsage.objects.all()
    main_model_queryset = MainModel.objects.all()
    pump_type_queryset = PumpType.objects.all()
    context = {
        "product_queryset": product_queryset,
        "usage_queryset": usage_queryset,
        "sub_usage_queryset": sub_usage_queryset,
        "main_model_queryset": main_model_queryset,
        "pump_type_queryset": pump_type_queryset,
    }
    return render(request, "products/products_usage_main.html", context)


def sidebar_data(request):
    usage_queryset = Usage.objects.all()
    sub_usage_queryset = SubUsage.objects.all()
    main_model_queryset = MainModel.objects.all()
    pump_type_queryset = PumpType.objects.all()
    context = {
        "usage_queryset": usage_queryset,
        "sub_usage_queryset": sub_usage_queryset,
        "main_model_queryset": main_model_queryset,
        "pump_type_queryset": pump_type_queryset,
    }
    return render(request, "products/products_sidebar.html", context)
```

And the sidebar template is as shown below:

```
  <ul class="nav flex-column list-unstyled my-3 ms-3">
    {% for usage_item in usage_queryset %}
      <li class="nav-item p-2 ms-4">
        <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none nm-text-color fw-semibold"
           data-bs-toggle="collapse"
           data-bs-target="#usage_{{ usage_item.usage_name_fa }}">
           <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left me-2 icon-selector"></i>
            الکتروپمپ‌های {{ usage_item.usage_name_fa }}
        </a>
        <ul class="submenu collapse" id="usage_{{ usage_item.usage_name_fa }}"
          data-bs-parent="#nav_accordion">
          {% for sub_usage in sub_usage_queryset %}
            {% if sub_usage.usage == usage_item %}
              <li class="my-2 ms-4">
                <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none nm-text-color fw-semibold">
                  {{ sub_usage }}
                </a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

And now I'm creating a proucts main page for example, which should implement this sidebar.
I included this sidebar template in my products page template as shown below:

```
    <section>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 col-lg-4 px-0">
                    {% include "products/products_sidebar.html" %}
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-lg-8">
                    content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Now, I know that without a URL, the view `sidebar_data()` won't be called, and for now my urls are as shown below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("application/", products_usage_main, name="products_usage_main"),
    path("application/<str:pk>", product_detail, name="product_detail"),
]
```

And as expected, context data sent in the `sidebar_data()` view, will not be sent and so my sidebar will not be populated with the data.
How am I supposed to acheive this?
There is one way, in which I have to send the queryset data sent to sidebar in all the different product pages, but I think there should be a more sufficient way.
Your help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Could you add the demonstration of your views file?

Comment: What do you mean by " demonstration of your views file"? Should I add the whole views.py file?

Comment: Yes if you can, also check the demonstration provided in the answer if it helps

Comment: I added the views.py file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to pass the same context in your all views. A simple demonstration of your views would be as follows:

views.py

```py
# Since these context will be common to all views it would be written outside any view function
def get_common_queryset():
    usage_queryset = Usage.objects.all()
    sub_usage_queryset = SubUsage.objects.all()
    main_model_queryset = MainModel.objects.all()
    pump_type_queryset = PumpType.objects.all()
    queryset_dictionary = {
        "usage_queryset": usage_queryset,
        "sub_usage_queryset": sub_usage_queryset,
        "main_model_queryset": main_model_queryset,
        "pump_type_queryset": pump_type_queryset,
    }
    return queryset_dictionary



# and in every other views
def products_usage_main(request):
    ...
    context_of_view = {
    ...
    }
    common_context = get_common_queryset()
    context = {**context_of_view, **common_context} # dictionary expansion
    return render(request, "template_name.html", context)
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, It should work; still I was looking for a way that I won't have to send the data through all the views. Is it possible?

Comment: There is a problem with this solution. You have written some queries outside of the views, so they will run only once and only when loading server.